# Duplicate API error while creating API on WSO2 API Manager 1.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to create a API using a tenant user. But I am getting "Duplicate API name error". Previously I had created a API with Name `"BillingAccount"` and deleted from publisher. But now I am getting this error.[image]

But When I click on browse there is no API listed with that name. I have also restarted the server several time. [image]

Comment: are there any errors on wso2carbon.log ?

Comment: How did you deleted the API?

Answer (score 0):

Was the previous API deleted via the management console?

This could happen if the previous API was deleted from the management console.

When an API is deleted from the management console, it will only be deleted from the registry (i.e. meta data) 
The recommended approach to delete an API is through the API Publisher web application.

Comment: how to resolve this, if it was deleted from API console?